# Test the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n\space log\space n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

So I encountered this problem in *S. K. Mapa*'s book *Introduction to Real Analysis*. The answer to this question is given as below:

> The series is $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n\space log\space n}$ convergent by Abel's test, since $\sum\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ is a convergent series and the sequence $\{\frac{1}{log \space n}\}_{2}^{\infty}$ is a monotone decreasing sequence bounded below.

I don't understand how $\sum\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ is a convergent series because $\sum\dfrac{1}{n}$ is a divergent series.
If I take $\sum u_n = \sum \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$, then $\sum |u_n|= \sum \dfrac{1}{n}$ which is actually a divergent series and $u_n$ cannot be convergent.

But in my textbook, it says that series is convergent. How is it possible?

Comment: [Hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series).